# Sharepoint folder access problem

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a strange problem and here are the facts:

1. I have a group created in sharepoint
2. I have created folders as the system account
3. 2 people in this group can't access the folders I created from their laptop over vpn. They get a page cannot be found. They can however access these folders on their desktop which is not using vpn.
4. Everyone else can access the folder in this group.

Does anyone have a clue what might be the problem?

This is sharepoint 2007 btw.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 1):

can they access other sharepoint folder/webpart ?

Everyone else can access through vpn, is it what you mean ?

Check for difference between their laptop and others:

- Is the site in their intranet zone ?
- Do they have the same dns suffix as others on the networks card ?
- Are they using wifi/ethernet as the others ?
- Do they have a local subnet behind their adsl that is the same as your subnet (192.168.X.X for example) ?
- Are they prompt to authenticate again ?